# R: counting multiple occurences of strings in multiple (!) columns

Tags: r, count, plyr, frequency

and thanks already for a ton of articles about my (not yet asked) problem, which got me quite further!

But still, I can't help it, but raise another one of those counting questions:

I have a big data set of around 30,000 rows and five columns, filled with names. Altogether there are around 14,000 different names in the df. Now what I am interested in, is the co-occurence of names in a row, but independent on whether a name is in column 1,2,3 and so on.

As an example the matrix can look like this (probably horribly coded):

```
testmatrix<- matrix(nrow=52, ncol=5)


for (i in 1:5) {

    testmatrix[,i]<-(sample(letters, replace=T))

    }

data<-as.data.frame(testmatrix)
```

My final matrix should then have (in the test example) 26 rows and 26 columns (in the "real" dataset 14,000x14,000), with all co-occurences. I could work with `aggregate` (I thought), but then I'd have to produce a multitude of dfs for each column-dyad (1-2, 1-3, 1-4, etc.) - maybe there is a unique and simpler function for doing that (maybe even also in the plyr package?).

Thanks to everyone already, I hope this is an easy one for you ;)

Best,
Al

Comment: Your code is not working, you want `testmatrix[,i]<-sample(letters, 5, replace=T)`. Also, I don't fully understand how the output should look like. What should be in the rows and columns of the desired matrix?

Comment: Hi Henrik,thanks for the fast reply! And sorry for the wrong code (I had a shorter example with 52 rows, i.e. a multiple of the 26 letters). The output should have every unique name as variables (i.e. columns) and rows for each unique name as well. - Thhe cells should be filled with the frequency of each dyad's co-occurence in a row of the original df. - In the example df it should thus create a 26x26 matrix for every letter with the frequency of each dyad in the corresponding cells. Is that clearer? Thanks again!

Comment: No it is not clear. show the desired output in a small example. for example a matrix of 3 rows, 4 columns with 6 letters

Comment: Ok, I uploaded a [picture](http://www.file-upload.net/download-7878908/bsp3.PNG.html)
 of an example 5x5 results matrix, because it should have the same number of rows and columns (hope that is ok), which are then automatically the 5 letters. The Numbers then are the co-occurences (frequencies), of a and b in one row of the original df, a and c and so on. This is of course bigger later. Is that clearer? (Sorry for the misunderstanding...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might help you get started ...

```
# an example matrix of letters
m <- matrix(sample(letters, 30, replace=T), nrow=6, ncol=5)
m

# the unique values in the matrix
vals <- sort(unique(as.vector(m)))

# rearrange the data so that each value is a column
bigm <- t(apply(m, 1, function(row) match(vals, row, nomatch=0)))
colnames(bigm) <- vals
bigm

# count the co-occurences of each value (diagonal is total number of rows with that value)
crossprod(bigm>0)
```

Comment: Woohooooo, thanks! I have to try on the big dataset though, but this looks perfect. I am not wure how it works, but it does, apparently. I'll tell you, whether it worked with the rest. Thank you all, highly appreciated!

Comment: This is incorrect, as it miscounts matches of a character with itself.

Comment: oh, ok, do you mean it counts them as too often? In my bigger dataset, I get (although `ncol` puts out 5) a undefined columns selected error. Do you guys have an idea for that too (plus the incorrectnes)?

Comment: the above solution lumps together occurrences with co-occurences, so if `a` occurs twice in a row, the `a`-`a` entry is 3, two for the number of times `a` occurs plus one for the co-occurence of `a` and `a` in that row, does that make sense?

Comment: oh, I see - but by definition every single name can only occur once in a row. so that should work, right? - any ideas on the undefined columns selected thing?

Comment: Still won't work.  even if a row is `a b c d e`, `a-a` through `e-e` will be one where it should be 0.  You'll have to be more specific on what code produces that error

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't think of a cute functional way to do this, but it's surprisingly fast.

```
x <- matrix(as.character(sample(1:14000,30000*5,replace=T)),30000,5)
countmat <- matrix(0,14000,14000,dimnames=list(as.character(1:14000),as.character(1:14000)))
for(i in 1:nrow(x))
  {
    xc <- table(x[i,],x[i,])
    countmat[rownames(xc),colnames(xc)] <- countmat[rownames(xc),colnames(xc)]+xc
  }
```

EDIT:

I then realized there is a cute functional way to do this, but it's too memory intensive for my machine

```
x <- matrix(as.character(sample(1:14000,30000*5,replace=T)),30000,5)
cx <- adply(x,.margins=1,.fun=function(x)table(x,x))
```

Comment: Hi and thanks! The second one is to hard for my machine as well, and I cannot get the first one to run (a dimnames error - I added one parantheses for the matrix command, right? - but anyway, the one down below seems to work, just a second...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The first solution should now work.  If you try the second solution with a smaller matrix, you'll find it works as well(e.g `adply(x[1:30,].margins=1,.fun=function(x)table(x,x))`).